# Shoes are not boots

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This question [Shoes for hiking in Australia?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19415/shoes-for-hiking-in-australia) has been closed as a dupe of [What do I need to look for in good, quality hiking boots?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/101/what-do-i-need-to-look-for-in-good-quality-hiking-boots) .

However, the dupe target is about hiking **boots**, and the question is about **shoes**.

People will go hiking in shoes instead of boots all of the time, in fact that is was approach shoes are designed for. Since the OP is asking for shoes to do

> some minor rock climbing in Australia.

as well, **boots are not particularly appropriate for the use case.**

Can we **reopen this since it is in fact not a dupe?**

Comment: Looks like it has been re-opened